# Spring MVC binding an enum to an input

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm having trouble creating an edit page. One of the inputs should be bound to part of the object model which is an enum:

```html
public class BonusFormData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
    @JsonSerialize(
        using = BonusTypeSerializer.class
    )
    @JsonDeserialize(
        using = BonusTypeDeserializer.class
    )
    private BonusType bonusType;
    
.......
```

```html
public class BonusCampaignRequest extends CampaignRequest implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 319551486808177424L;
...
    private BonusFormData bonusFormData;
    
 ...
```

Then ,  I bind it to my model like so:

```html
BonusCampaignRequest cr = loadCampaignRequest( campaignId, partnerId );
model.addAttribute("campaignRequest", cr);
```

When I attempt to bind an input to  the bonusType field, it throws this error:

```html
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "undefined"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.java:113)
...

    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "undefined"
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:115)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:78)

.....
```

Here's the BonusType class:

```html
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by FernFlower decompiler)
//

package com.gameaccount.isight.bonusengine.bonus.domain;

public enum BonusType {
    NONE(0, "None"),
    FIXED_BONUS(1, "Fixed Bonus"),
    CASHBACK_BONUS(2, "Cashback Bonus"),
    DEPOSIT_MATCH(3, "Deposit Match"),
    PURCHASE_OFFER_BONUS(4, "Purchase Offer Bonus"),
    FREE_SPINS(5, "Free spins"),
    SPORTSBOOK(6, "Sportsbook Bonus"),
    WIDGETS(7, "Widgets Bonus"),
    UNKNOWN(999, "Unknown");

    private final int value;
    private final String description;

    private BonusType(int value, String description) {
        this.value = value;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public static BonusType fromInt(Integer fromValue) {
        if (fromValue == null) {
            return NONE;
        } else {
            switch(fromValue) {
            case 0:
                return NONE;
            case 1:
                return FIXED_BONUS;
            case 2:
                return CASHBACK_BONUS;
            case 3:
                return DEPOSIT_MATCH;
            case 4:
                return PURCHASE_OFFER_BONUS;
            case 5:
                return FREE_SPINS;
            case 6:
                return SPORTSBOOK;
            case 7:
                return WIDGETS;
            default:
                return UNKNOWN;
            }
        }
    }

    public static BonusType fromDescription(String description) {
        BonusType[] var1 = values();
        int var2 = var1.length;

        for(int var3 = 0; var3 < var2; ++var3) {
            BonusType bonusType = var1[var3];
            if (bonusType.description.equalsIgnoreCase(description)) {
                return bonusType;
            }
        }

        return NONE;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
}
```

How do I bind an input field to an enum type within my data model?

Comment: Seems like BonusType is expecting a number not a string, and the string you are sending is undefined.

Comment: I inherited this application so I don't know where all the bodies are buried.  Can anyone explain where the conversion for BonusType might be found?

Comment: In the BonusType Class. Share that class please.

Comment: added the BonusType Class